# Turbo.visit('/') not working with Webpacker in Rails 6.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks, webpacker

I am setting up `Turbo` in a Rails 6.1.3 app with webpacker. Seems it is running as it should, except for one issue. I can't reference it in my js files:

```js
// app/javascript/javascripts/shared.js

Turbo.visit('/');
```

raises an error in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Turbo is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (shared.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4490)
    at dispatch (turbo.es2017-esm.js:387)
    at Session.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbo.es2017-esm.js:4822)
    at Session.pageBecameInteractive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:4718)
    at PageObserver.pageIsInteractive (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3880)
    at HTMLDocument.PageObserver.interpretReadyState (turbo.es2017-esm.js:3840)
```

Any ideas?

This is my configuration:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbo from "@hotwired/turbo"
import "jquery"
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')
Rails.start()
```

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Rails: '@rails/ujs',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was the setup that made it work:

```js
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
window.Turbo = Turbo
Rails.start()
```

Adding `window.Turbo` made it available outside the scope of `application.js`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// app/javascript/javascripts/shared.js
import Turbo from "@hotwired/turbo"
Turbo.visit('/');
```

`import` does not create a global which is shared across your files. Instead it imports a module into the current scope. Each file is its own scope.

See:

- [MDN: import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
- [MDN: Javascript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)
- [Webpacker Module Methods](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended)

Comment: seems that I can't import Turbo from `app/javascript/javascripts/shared.js`. The error is: `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`. However, when I replace `import Turbo from "@hotwired/turbo"` with `window.Turbo = require("@hotwired/turbo")` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`, things seems to work. It does not seem like I broke anything else, but not sure. What do you think of this solution?